# Apache Airavata dependency in Maven

Tags: maven

I'm building a Java application which has a dependency on the Apache Airavata project. I can get it up and running by putting all dependency jar's on the classpath but I have problems setting up the project using Maven.

Problem seems to be some maven repositories are not available. I tried this a couple of months ago with the same result.

**Update**

I got an answer on the Airavata mailing list that they were aware of the problem, that they supposedly had fixed it and are planning to work away away the dependency. Still, the server does not seem to work:

http://markmail.org/search/+list:org.apache.airavata.users#query:%20list%3Aorg.apache.airavata.users+page:1+mid:y37nleni7hocoftg+state:results

Anyhow, I have now realized that I should use `airavata-messenger-client`, and that is possible to use with maven with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.airavata</groupId>
    <artifactId>airavata-messenger-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.airavata</groupId>
    <artifactId>airavata-messenger-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Error message**

`The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '[hidden]\.m2\repository\org\apache\airavata\airavata-message-broker\0.5\airavata-message-broker-0.5.jar'`

`[ERROR] [..] Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.airavata:airavata-message-broker:jar:0.5 (compile)]: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for xmlbeans:xbean:jar:2.5.0: 
Could not transfer artifact xmlbeans:xbean:pom:2.5.0 from/to ogce.m2.all (http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090/archiva/repository/ogce.m2.all): 
Connection to http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090 refused: 
Connection refused: connect`

**pom.xml**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.apache.org-public</id>
        <name>Apache</name>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.airavata</groupId>
        <artifactId>airavata-message-broker</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: As I can see in the repository, `airavata` artifact is a zip archive. And you probably need a jar artifact. There are other artifacts that have name starting with `airavata-`. Maybe you should look at them.

Comment: That seems to be right. Most likely I should be using `airavata-message-broker`. Though the repositories it depend on seems to be down and have been down for the last couple of months.

Comment: I asked a question in the Airavata usergroup and got the following answer: `We are having problems with this server and are
in process of fixing it. We will let you know when Archiva comes up.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airavata has some third party jars pulled from a repo. Please copy paste the following two repos to your pom and see if the problem goes

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Maven Central</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <name>ogce.m2.all</name>
    <id>ogce.m2.all</id>
    <url>http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090/archiva/repository/ogce.m2.all</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Repository http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090/archiva/repository/ogce.m2.all looks down to me. Can anyone else access it?

Comment: Never had to use it so might as well close this, even though the repo still seems to be down